# How to convert Cardano Address?

Tags: address, blockfrost, cardano-address

Cardano has a number of different types of address from receiving address to enterprise address and many others.

My question is in two parts:

1. where can I find an exhaustive list of all address types?
2. given an address how can I get all other address connected to it?

Example given a receive address how do I get the stake address or the address blockfrost uses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About address formation and extracting Stake keys, you can read the [CIP-0019](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/governance/cardano-improvement-proposals/CIP-0019)

1. *Edit: this was reply to old question (about address, not address type) : This question does not make sense - you can have close to infinite addresses, you can only query addresses that have been used on chain (even then, you should be able to work your workflow logic a bit better than to scan millions of addresses on chain). If you're only interested in grabbing stake key from an address *already on chain* i.e. has a transaction against it - while using blockfrost, use [this](https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Addresses/paths/%7E1addresses%7E1%7Baddress%7D/get) endpoint.
   As regards address types, you can find the CIP above for common ones , while all concepts listed in docs [here](https://docs.cardano.org/core-concepts/cardano-addresses)
2. You can use the left sidebar on API docs for available endpoints, for the specific query for Account, you can use [this](https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Accounts/paths/%7E1accounts%7E1%7Bstake_address%7D%7E1addresses/get) endpoint.

Comment: Slightly changed the question, does it make better sense now? What else do you think adds confusion? I'm happy to change it as the question might help someone else later on

Comment: Yip - question now is correct (tho now my answer to point 1 doesnt make sense) =] edited the reply accordingly

Comment: Thanks man appricate that