# How To Get All Transactions of Associated With an Address In A Given Interval?

Tags: transaction, address, api, blockfrost, cardano-address

okay so given some reciving address such as `addr1qxq7k07cnt8vstdmygu7lpw0tyyssu4trs27qq6f7xjpmvrdrr3j8j5k5yacga4ckv6lnx4p0la57q7nf24eszqk0r2q9axgqv` how can I use a service like `BlockFrost` (or any other API) to get a list of all transactions associated with that address during a time interval between `T` and `T+N` ?

I am only concerned with some parts of the data and don't require the full info (i.e. not like `Cardano Scan`). The things I'm interested in are:

1. time of the transaction
2. assets received/sent (only the ones that moved not the full `UTXO` list)
3. Counter Party Address
4. quantity of each token moved

Comment: Have  a look at https://github.com/txpipe/oura or https://github.com/txpipe/scrolls

Comment: Okay thanks I'll do that

Comment: I had a look, but I would like to ask if there's anything for python. I have already written a lot of code in python that I want to easily be compatible with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address mentioned does not have any transactions associated with it.
If you're talking about transactions against account (not addresses, you can derive account by decoding bech32, and extracting keys as already asked in [this post](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/8528/how-to-convert-cardano-address) ):

1. get list of addresses known on chain using account address (example [here](https://api.koios.rest/#get-/account_addresses) )
2. Post those addresses to grab transaction (example [here](https://api.koios.rest/#post-/address_txs)
3. Post returned tx to query tx_info (example endpoint [here](https://api.koios.rest/#post-/address_txs), where you can also specify `_after_block_height` and use verticle/horizontal filters to extract only information you need)